# AFIncrementalStore Problems fetching multiple remote relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I have a problem with `AFIS` fetching remote relationships, i'm connecting to Apigee API, properly setting relationships at

```
- (NSDictionary *)representationsForRelationshipsFromRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)representation
                                                           ofEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity
                                                       fromResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
```

then, spent a lot of time debugging, found that relation name and URL build is correct, exactly as i want but the AFHTTPClient never makes the network call, found out the reason in method:

```
- (id)newValueForRelationship:(NSRelationshipDescription *)relationship
              forObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
                  withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
                        error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
```

line

```
if ([request URL] && (![[context existingObjectWithID:objectID error:nil] hasChanges]))
```

because `hasChanges` always returns `YES`.

Any advice ?

Comment: hasChanges returning YES indicates there are unsaved changes to the NSManagedObject with objectID. Look in your code where that object has been inserted, deleted or changed and make sure those unsaved changes have been committed to the context with save:. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @gutoaraujo , first off thanks for the response, i'm giving it a shot now ,as that was the default behaviour of AFIS inserting remote relationships, do you think there's something i'm missing ? or it's just not a good idea to use AFIS with API that returns many remote relationships instead of enclosing the whole relationship object with response ?

Comment: Np. A good place to start would be to look at how you are mapping those relationships in your AFRESTClient subclass. Take a look at the Twitter Client example (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/blob/master/Examples/Twitter%20Client/Classes/AppDotNetIncrementalStore.m).